# How to prevent minimize of child window when parent window minimizes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

If I show a new non-modal child window using .Show(frmParent), and then the parent window is minimized, the child will get minimized automatically as well.

What is the best way to prevent this?

EDIT: The child window **must be non-modal**, and it **must have the parent set**.

Comment: Just use `Show()` and remove the Child / Parent relationship.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is necessary. See my coment to Fischermaen's answer.

Comment: @jiri why is it necessary to use the parent form property? Form.Owner simple returns a reference to a form - you shouldn't need to actually set the owner to get that reference.

Comment: @David: The inbuilt property ensures that the child window is displayed on top of the parent window, even when the child window is not actually "always on top" (TopMost) and the parent is. I can imagine that handling this myself would be problematic.

Comment: This MSDN topic would be a good read to become clearer on the terminology and implications of the various relationships between windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called "owned window", not child window.  Windows ensures that the owned window is always on top of its owner.  Which implies it *has* to be minimized when the owner is minimized.

Winforms does however support changing the owner on the fly.  This sample code worked well:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Form ownedWindow;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (ownedWindow != null) return;
        ownedWindow = new Form2();
        ownedWindow.FormClosed += delegate { ownedWindow = null; };
        ownedWindow.Show(this);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Trap the minimize and restore commands
        if (m.Msg == 0x0112 && ownedWindow != null) {
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0xf020) ownedWindow.Owner = null;
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0xf120) {
                ownedWindow.Owner = this;
                ownedWindow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hans, this looks great! Thank you, you just made many users of my software happier :) Do you think that it would also be possible to trap and throw away the minimize message directly in the owned window?

Comment: Set the form's MinimizeBox property to False.

Comment: Actually, what I meant is that when the owned window receives the message it should minimize because its parent got minimized, can I detect that and throw it away?

Answer (score 0):

If the child window should behave like a dialog (you cannot interact with the parent window as long as it is open) then call `.ShowDialog(frmParent)`.

Comment: Nope, the child window must be non-modal independent window; not a dialog. And it must have the parent set due to complex "always on top" logic (both windows can be independently always on top, plus the parent window can have other MODAL child windows).